# Existence and uniqueness of initial value problem in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

consider the following equation:
$$
y'=y^{\frac{1}{3}}, \,y(0)=0
$$

My question is how can I prove the existence and uniqueness of solutions of this initial value problem without solving the equation?

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: You can prove existence by writing down a solution. But uniqueness does not hold.

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot.

Comment: @user133140, the trivial solution comes to mind.

Comment: @HansEngler, oh you are right, it is not if and only if.

Comment: The theorem you used just now is a little bit different from the theorem I learned, and in my text book, f(x,y) should be linear. Maybe I need to look up other text books. @Nameless

Comment: I hope the answer works well for you.